# Declaring a function with different function specifiers

Tags: c, language-lawyer, function-declaration, noreturn

Consider this C code:

```c
_Noreturn void exit(int status);
void exit(int status);

int main(void) {
    exit(0);
}
```

It declares the `exit` function twice, once with the `_Noreturn` function specifier, and once without. This seems like it should be Undefined Behavior, but I can't find anything concrete in the standard that says so, and I don't get any compiler warnings about it no matter how high I set my warning level. Is it actually UB, or is it okay? And since the C standard says `exit` is `_Noreturn`, if I only had the declaration that doesn't have that, would that be UB or okay?

Comment: What is the difference between `_Noreturn void` and just `void`?

Comment: @ScottHunter `void` means it returns with no value. `_Noreturn` means it doesn't return at all.

Comment: Which version of the standard are you reading? The [`_Noreturn`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/_Noreturn) specifier has been deprecated in favor of the [`[[noreturn]]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/attributes/noreturn) attribute in the C23 standard. Please add the specific C standard version as a tag to your question.

Comment: It might be worth noting that the `_Noreturn` specifier (and the `[[noreturn]]` attribute) is for the *function*, not for the return type. It might be that it's only the return type (and argument types of course) that needs to be the same if you have multiple declarations. The function specifiers or attributes might follow along. Also, such attributes are voluntary. A function that calls `exit` will not return, but you don't have to mark it as "noreturn". It seems to be more a note to the compiler that to check the function definition, that it doesn't actually return.

Comment: Furthermore, a "noreturn" function might actually "return" through other means than a `return` statement or ending its execution. For example by a `longjmp` call. So while it's a good hint, it might not actually be truthful.

Comment: Even if it is valid, the question stands - what such a double declaration is achieving?

Comment: @Barmar: “`void` means it returns with no value”: A `void` return type means **if** the function returns, it does not return a value. It does not mean it does return.

Comment: @EricPostpischil But `_Noreturn` asserts positively that it will never return. A `void` function might not return, or it might return with no value.

Comment: @Barmar: My point is the sentence “`void` means it returns with no value” is false. A `void` return type does not mean the function returns with no value, because the function may not return at all.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I agree, I'm admitting that my earlier statement was incomplete. But in terms of the difference that Scott asked about, the important thing is the assertion. `_Noreturn` implies `void`, but not the other way around. But you're not allowed to omit the return type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it actually UB, or is it okay?

Presumably you are concerned about whether these declarations violate some rule regarding declaring identifiers twice, notably compatibility. C 2018 6.2.7 2 says:

> All declarations that refer to the same object or function shall have compatible type; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

The rules for compatibility of function types are specified in C 2018 6.7.6.3 15. Briefly, they say:

- The return types shall be compatible.
- If they both have parameter type lists, the lists have the same number of parameters, both have `...` or not, and the corresponding parameter types are compatible (after removing qualifiers from the parameter types and adjusting function and array types to pointers).
- Otherwise, the parameter parts of the declarations have to satisfy various requirements that do not concern us here.

These rules do not say the function specifiers have to satisfy any requirements. So the two declarations you show declare `exit` with compatible types and therefore satisfy 6.2.7 2.

> And since the C standard says exit is _Noreturn, if I only had the declaration that doesn't have that, would that be UB or okay?

It does not appear to violate any rule in C 2018. As [Jonathan Leffler’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78196282/298225) notes, this changes in the expected C 2023 standard.

Answer (score 6):

#### What the standards say

The C23 standard (or, at least, the [N3054](https://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n3054.pdf) draft of it) is quite clear:

> §6.7.12.6 The `noreturn` and `_Noreturn` attributes
>
> **Description**
>
> When `_Noreturn` is used as an attribute token (instead of a function specifier), the constraints and semantics are identical to that of the `noreturn` attribute token. Use of `_Noreturn` as an attribute token is an obsolescent feature<sup>187)</sup>.
>
> **Constraints**
>
> The `noreturn` attribute shall be applied to the identifier in a function declaration. No attribute argument clause shall be present.
>
> **Semantics**
>
> The first declaration of a function shall specify the `noreturn` attribute if any declaration of that function specifies the `noreturn` attribute. If a function is declared with the `noreturn` attribute in one translation unit and the same function is declared without the `noreturn` attribute in another translation unit, the behavior is undefined.
>
> <sup>187)</sup> `[[_Noreturn]]` and `[[noreturn]]` are equivalent attributes to support code that includes `<stdnoreturn.h>`, because that header defines `noreturn` as a macro that expands to `_Noreturn`.

The 'attribute token' refers to the new notation in C23 like `[[noreturn]]`, as opposed to the simpler `_Noreturn` function specifier in C11 and C18.  Attribute tokens were not a part of C11 or C18.

The C11 standard was not as clear about this (see [§6.7.4 Function specifiers](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.4), which does not mention such restrictions AFAIK).

The C23 standard §6.7.4 Function specifiers says:

> A function declared with a `_Noreturn` function specifier shall not return to its caller. The attribute `[[noreturn]]` provides similar semantics. The `_Noreturn` function specifier is an obsolescent feature (6.7.12.6).

Also, §6.7.12 Atributes ¶2 of C23 says:

> Support for any of the standard attributes specified in this document is implementation-defined and optional. For an attribute token (including an attribute prefixed token) not specified in this document, the behavior is implementation-defined. Any attribute token that is not supported by the implementation is ignored.

Further, §6.7.12.1 General ¶3 of C23 says:

> A strictly conforming program using a standard attribute remains strictly conforming in the absence of that attribute.<sup>185)</sup>
>
> <sup>185)</sup> Standard attributes specified by this document can be parsed but ignored by an implementation without changing the semantics of a correct program; the same is not true for attributes not specified by this document.

The C23 standard contains many rules that I have not mentioned (section 6.7.12 covers pages 142-151). To see the details, get the draft (or the published standard if it is available).

#### Applying the rules

Under the rules of C23, the code in the question is valid:

```
_Noreturn void exit(int status);
void exit(int status);
```

However, were the lines reversed, it would probably be invalid (assuming no other declarations of `exit()` were present before these lines in the translation unit) because of the "first declaration" semantic.  If the `_Noreturn` was replaced by `[[noreturn]]` (or any legitimate variant spelling — there are alternatives), then the reverse sequence would definitely violate the "first declaration" semantic rule.

Answer (score 1):

### Through C17

> It declares the exit function twice, once with the `_Noreturn` function specifier, and once without. This seems like it should be Undefined Behavior, but I can't find anything concrete in the standard that says so

The specifications for function specifiers have nothing to say about the matter, so the primary consideration seems to be that

> All declarations in the same scope that refer to the same object or function shall specify compatible
> types.

(C17 6.7/4)

And what does it mean for two function types to be compatible? C17 paragraph 6.7.6.3/15 explains:

> For two function types to be compatible, both shall specify compatible
> return types.

Check.

> Moreover, the parameter
> type lists, if both are present, shall agree in the number of
> parameters and in use of the ellipsis terminator; corresponding
> parameters shall have compatible types.

Check.

> [ various provisions not applying to the case in question ]

Moot.

So it seems that the two declarations *do* declare compatible types.

But what about the discrepancy in the use of the `_Noreturn` specifier, you ask?  The concept of composite type comes into play here:

> A composite type can be constructed from two types that are compatible; it is a type that is compatible
> with both of the two types and satisfies the following conditions:
>
> [...]
>
> - If both types are function types with parameter type lists, the type of each parameter in the
>   composite parameter type list is the composite type of the corresponding parameters.

The general idea is that the attributes of the type of an identifier can be specified jointly by multiple declarations that are not all identical to each other.  It may be more familiar to you with the `static` storage-class specifier, the `inline` function specifier, or function declarations differing in whether they provide prototypes.

> I don't get any compiler warnings about it no matter how high I set my warning level. Is it actually UB, or is it okay?

> And since the C standard says exit is `_Noreturn`, if I only had the declaration that doesn't have that, would that be UB or okay?

Yes, because adding or removing `_Noreturn` does not affect type compatibility.

### In C23

... it is more nuanced.  As far as I can tell, `_Noreturn` still does not impact type compatibility, but there are new rules specific to it (via the `noreturn` attribute) that come into play, as described in [@JonathanLeffler's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78196282/2402272).